# Macro that makes a Excel-list/log of mails in an account/folder

Tags: email, excel, outlook, vba

Here is my macro. I assumed that I could understand the codes and then edit it and get what I wanted
First: The macro abends whitout any progress at all: "Compile error: userdefined typenot defined"
I dont even know what this meens :)
(I use the macro now in an new and emty workbook)

```
Sub ListAllItemsInInbox()
    Dim OLF As Outlook.MAPIFolder, CurrUser As String
    Dim EmailItemCount As Integer, i As Integer, EmailCount As Integer
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Workbooks.Add ' create a new workbook
    ' add headings
    Cells(1, 1).Formula = "Subject"
    Cells(1, 2).Formula = "Recieved"
    Cells(1, 3).Formula = "Attachments"
    Cells(1, 4).Formula = "Read"
    With Range("A1:D1").Font
        .Bold = True
        .Size = 14
    End With
    Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual
    Set OLF = GetObject("", _
        "Outlook.Application").GetNamespace("MAPI").GetDefaultFolder(olFolderInbox)
    EmailItemCount = OLF.Items.Count
    i = 0: EmailCount = 0
    ' read e-mail information
    While i < EmailItemCount
        i = i + 1
        If i Mod 50 = 0 Then Application.StatusBar = "Reading e-mail messages " & _
            Format(i / EmailItemCount, "0%") & "..."
        With OLF.Items(i)
            EmailCount = EmailCount + 1
            Cells(EmailCount + 1, 1).Formula = .Subject
            Cells(EmailCount + 1, 2).Formula = Format(.ReceivedTime, "dd.mm.yyyy hh:mm")
            Cells(EmailCount + 1, 3).Formula = .Attachments.Count
            Cells(EmailCount + 1, 4).Formula = Not .UnRead
        End With
    Wend
    Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
    Set OLF = Nothing
    Columns("A:D").AutoFit
    Range("A2").Select
    ActiveWindow.FreezePanes = True
    ActiveWorkbook.Saved = True
    Application.StatusBar = False
End Sub
```

Comment: What kind of trouble does it cause? Blows up your pc? Disintegrates Outlook into thin air? :D Give us the exact error message that you get and probably we would be able to help.

Comment: :)
I am really on scratch here, it seems all alternative macros dont accept Dim FolderTgt As MAPIFolder and such codes.

Comment: The error appears as: Compile error - User-defined type is not defined
I have no clue how to get more into this ....

Comment: Ok. Now we are heading somewhere :) To start with. Did you set a reference to Outlook from Excel VBA if you are running the code from Excel.

Comment: [FYI on how to set a reference](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/bb206737%28v=office.12%29.aspx)

Comment: Tryed, read the advice, but dont get it (sorry)

Comment: Where are you running the code from? Also can you share the code that you currently have?

Comment: Well
I will run the macro from Excel, and the task is to transfer key-data from all in-and outgoing mail in a specific mailacount into an Excel-list (or log).

Comment: See the 2nd question in y prev comment

Comment: Too long to paste .... obviously

Comment: Need to see the begining of the sub (including declarations)

Comment: I really appreciate your help, but I feel totaly lost.

Comment: What's hard is copying the first couple of lines from your code and pasting it in your question? :)

Comment: Sub ListAllItemsInInbox()
Dim OLF As Outlook.MAPIFolder, CurrUser As String
Dim EmailItemCount As Integer, i As Integer, EmailCount As Integer
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Workbooks.Add ' create a new workbook
    ' add headings
    Cells(1, 1).Formula = "Subject"
    Cells(1, 2).Formula = "Recieved"
    Cells(1, 3).Formula = "Attachments"
    Cells(1, 4).Formula = "Read"
    With Range("A1:D1").Font
        .Bold = True
        .Size = 14

Comment: Edit your question please ans paste the code there. It is difficult to read the code in comments.

Comment: Try this. Change `Outlook.MAPIFolder` to `Object` and if it works then we will take it from there.

Comment: :9 That made some progress, but caused Run-time error '5': Invalid procedure or argument in code:
    Set OLF = GetObject("", _
        "Outlook.Application").GetNamespace("MAPI").GetDefaultFolder(olFolderInbox)

Comment: Replace `olFolderInbox` with `6` and try again.

Comment: This made something happen :)
Now I have something to work on ...thanks a lot
(maybe I ask again)

Comment: I am posting an answer with the explanations... almost done

Comment: ..and I still dont understand what was wrong :)
Thanks!!!!

Comment: Wait for my answer :)

Answer (score 0):

As stated in the [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/bb206737%28v=office.12%29.aspx) Article, which I have already provided in the comments above, you can bind with MS Outlook either by `Late Binding (LB)` or `Early Binding (EB)` from MS Excel.

Now what exactly is LB and EB? For this I would again direct you to another [MSDN](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/245115) link.

When you are using EB, you have to set a reference to the relevant application from `Tools ~~> References` and set your reference to the relevant Outlook Object Library. For example

[image]

In Layman Terms, Excel now understands what `Outlook` and `MAPIFolder` is. Similarly `olFolderInbox` is an Outlook constant which has a value of `6`. So your original code would have worked without any errors if you would have set the reference.

When you are usign LB, you do not set a reference. You declare your objects as `Objects`. There are analyzed by Excel during runtime. More about this has already been covered in the link above. Also since we are late binding, we have to explicitly use `6` instead of `olFolderInbox` as that is what it's value is.

Hope this sets you on the right track. Do ask questions if you have any.

Comment: G@NilsMortenKirkedamBlakstad: Glad to be of help. Gotta go out for couple of hours. If you have any questions. Type them here and I will respond when I can. :)

Comment: Now its working almost as intended (hurray!!), but how can I choose what mail-box/folder to make this log/list from. We have a mailbox in this case named "MacroTest" we whant to log.